# Perform a repeatable operation on StringBuilder when button pressed

Tags: java, android, loops, button, stringbuilder

I have a `StringBulder strB = "123456";` and when a numerical button is pressed, i want the method to:

1. Delete first char from strB **(should be "23456")**
2. Append value from the button on the right side **(e.g. "1", so "234561")**
3. Have the resulting value **("234561")** be the strB value
4. Have the ability to press one button after the other and it changing the strB (e.g. pressing 2,4,9 now, should result in **steB = "561249"**) And with every one of the button presses the method would do its thing

How can I do that? I've been sitting over this for the past 3 days.
Tried String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer, for loops, if, none of them i could make working beyond a first button click, please help :/

Comment: What have you done to attempt to solve this on your own? Post what you have and what the exact problem you're stuck on is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out. If anyone runs into this problem, this worked for me. My ***input*** comes from onClick method, which sends a number as string ***"4"***, the loop triggers once, and it's ready to run again on the next onClick event.

***countdown*** is declared in the main method as
`private StringBuilder countdown = new StringBuilder(6).append("000000");`.

```
public void countDownTimer(String input){
        int inputLgt = input.length();
        if (clicks<7) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                if (inputLgt == 1) {
                    countdown.delete(0, 1);
                    countdown.append(input);
                } else if (inputLgt == 2) {
                    countdown.delete(0, 2);
                    countdown.append(input);
                } else if (inputLgt == 3) {
                    countdown.delete(5, 6);
                    countdown.insert(0,"0");
                }
            }
        }

        String strNew = countdown.toString();
        String h = strNew.substring(0, 2);
        String m = strNew.substring(2, 4);
        String s = strNew.substring(4, 6);
        String hms = h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s";

        editValue.setText(hms);
        String click = String.valueOf(clicks);
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "Clicks:", " "+click+" "+strNew);

    }
```